# Pass object in the constructor of an object

Tags: matlab, oop, constructor, properties, initialization

Suppose I have a class

```
classdef Dummy

    properties
        property    % to be assigned with an object
    end

    methods
        function obj = Dummy(in)
            % Constructor. Assign this object to `in.property`
            if nargin > 0
                in.property = obj;
            end
        end

    end
end
```

What I want is to by executing the code

```
z = Dummy();
z1 = Dummy(z);
```

I will have `z.property = z1` the `property` of `z` is assigned with the object `z1`

**But in practice, when I execute the above snippet, `z.property = []` is always empty. How do I achieve the behavior I want (preferably using the constructor)?**

---

I tried debugging this, and found that everything is fine even with the statement `in.property = obj;`. The problem appears when stepping out of the object, where `z.property=[]` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by specifying a `handle` superclass

```
classdef Dummy < handle

    properties
        property    % to be assigned with an object
    end

    methods
        function obj = Dummy(in)
            % Constructor. Assign this object to `in.property`
            if nargin > 0
                in.property = obj;
            end
        end

    end
end
```

such that the object is created as a reference. Otherwise, this `in.property = obj` will try to give a copy of the object, which makes it fails.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for pointing it out. My question was a wrong statement, not I changed it.